# How to @mention salesforce user in a slack slack post

Tags: sales-cloud, slack

How can I @mention salesforce user in a slack post?
What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Have you tried <@USERID>

Answer (score 0):

Using the Flow Slack Send Message action, if the parameter `Slack Message`

contains `<@theSlackUserName>` then it will render in slack with a blue box just as if you @mention'd the user directly in Slack

Example:

`Slack Message` looks like

```
I am a message <@fred.fubar> pay attention!
```

Then this will render in Slack as

```
I am a message @fred.fubar pay attention
```

with the @fred.fubar background indicating an @mention

Of course, standard Slack @mention [rules apply](https://slack.com/help/articles/205240127-Use-mentions-in-Slack#:%7E:text=If%20the%20person%20is%20part,a%20prompt%20to%20add%20them.) (i.e., if user is not a member of the channel you are posting to, they won't be notified in Slack.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a new field on the User record that stores the SlackId. I'm not aware of an automation for this yet, but export user Ids from Slack (Manage members), then upload with Dataloader.

In the flow, you'd reference the new Slack Id field you created with the mrkup listed by @cropredy.

ex: Hey <@{!$Record.Owner.Slack_Id__c}>, please see this message about an opportunity.